# How can I set up some type of Task or Initializer to load data in my Memcache on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, heroku

So I just pushed by first app up to Heroku for the first time and discovered that the initializer file I use in development to load up data in my cache was causing a recompile error so I "fixed" it with this dumb hack you can see [here](https://github.com/MKwenhua/petecvHeroku/blob/master/config/initializers/querycache.rb)

the file **querycache.rb**

```
@songs = Song.all   

@songs.each do |sng|
    Rails.cache.fetch(sng.song_title){sng}
end
top100 =  Song.where('num_stars > ?', 0 ).order('num_stars desc, total_score desc').includes(:categories).limit(100)
Rails.cache.fetch('Top100'){top100} 

trending_users = User.where('followers_count > ?', 0 ).order("reputation  desc").limit(10)
 Rails.cache.fetch('cool_crowd', :expires_in => 12.hours){trending_users} 
 newest_songs = Song.last(8)
 Rails.cache.fetch('newest_songs'){newest_songs} 
 just_joined = User.last(8)
 Rails.cache.fetch('newest_users'){just_joined}
```

I have read Heroku's documentation on caching, but this situation is a tad bit different. Although I do have more dynamic caching like fragment caching and other small optimizations, given the nature of my app it's important that I have all **:song_title** strings and objects stored in the cache so that my app can quickly process requests. So if there is anything such as maybe a rake task that can execute the code above, or some other way of getting these objects loaded in the cache when the server is up and running that would be great.

Sorry for the newbie question, I am still kind of new to rails and while I know there is an easy alternative, I am not exactly sure what it is.

**EDIT: I Found a solution to my problem**

Ok so in the **application.rb** file within the config folder I added this:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    config.after_initialize do
      @songs = Song.all 

      @songs.each do |sng|
       Rails.cache.fetch(sng.song_title){sng}
      end
      top100 =  Song.where('num_stars > ?', 0 ).order('num_stars desc, total_score desc').includes(:categories).limit(100).to_a
      Rails.cache.fetch('Top100'){top100} 

      trending_users = User.where('followers_count > ?', 0 ).order("reputation  desc").limit(10).to_a
      Rails.cache.fetch('cool_crowd', :expires_in => 12.hours){trending_users} 
      newest_songs = Song.last(8)
      Rails.cache.fetch('newest_songs'){newest_songs} 
      just_joined = User.last(8)
      Rails.cache.fetch('newest_users'){just_joined} 
    end
end
```

anyways, the objects I wanted to load in the initializer i just moved to the application file with the block command  **config.after_initialize do**. Now everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you precaching in an initializer? I would either do the caching directly where you use the data, e.g.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @trending_users = Rails.cache.fetch('cool_crowd', :expires_in => 12.hours) do
      User.where('followers_count > ?', 0).order(reputation: :desc).limit(10).to_a
    end
  end
end
```

Also, notice that I added a `to_a` to the end of the call. You must do this if you're caching your results, otherwise Rails will return a ActiveRecord relation, and you'll still end up executing the query.

If you use these methods often, you could add the method to User, e.g.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.cached_trending_users
    Rails.cache.fetch('cool_crowd', :expires_in => 12.hours) do
      User.where('followers_count > ?', 0).order(reputation: :desc).limit(10).to_a
    end
  end
end
```

My other thought is - why not just use the database? It looks like you're preloading your cache so that you can do

```
Rails.cache.read("Sandstorm") # => <Song id: 123, song_title: "Sandstorm", artist: "Darude">
```

When it's nearly as fast to just do `Song.find_by_song_title("Sandstorm")` as long as you put an index on your `songs` table for the `song_title` column.

Comment: I think that **.where** always returns an array. Anyways, while hitting the DB is not too slow, I think that due to the nature of the app the cache is a faster solution. The app has a world music api component and every time a user clicks on a country before I hit any API I see if the query has been called before if so, I have save the query string with an array of song_url's and then pull out all of the song objects from the cache. Additionally the Top_songs 100 list is a pretty complicated query since it requires sorting so I cache it right away.

Comment: `.where` does *not* return an array. It does when you call it in console because IRB will explicitly call `.to_s` on it, but when you cache it, the result is an ActiveRecord relation which does not contain any data. This is the way that `User.where(id: 123).where(name: "Ben")` chaining works while `User.where(id: 123).to_a.where(name: "Ben")` doesn't.

Comment: oh, I wasn't aware of that. I went into the console to see what you meant, and at first when using just **topsongs = Song.where(..)** I and then doing topsongs[0] it seemed to return the same thing, but I did notice on different after adding .to_a . The normal console return for **topsongs = Song.where(..)** returned **=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [object, object]** before the "Array", then I did what u said **topsongs = Song.where(..).to_a** the return was **=> [object, object]**. So you're right, but now I have a new question. What is the difference?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, and pointing out my misconception with **.where** I think I selected your answer as the top one, if that's what the green check means. Anyways, I appreciate the help!